# Why is the the temperature change due to the combustion of paraffin wax so high (10000 Kelvin)?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, combustion

I'm trying to work out the temperature change (I got something like 10k Kelvin,hotter than the Sun's core...) caused by the combustion of paraffin wax which has a  molar enthalpy of combustion $E^{wax}_{m}=15MJmol^{-1}$.
$$38O_2+C_{25}H_{52} \to 25CO_2 +26 H_2O \tag{1}$$
so for a given number of moles of oxygen $n_{O_2}$, the reaction requires $(1/38)n_{O_2} $ moles of wax ($C_{25}H_{52}$) and produces $(25/38)n_{O_2}$ moles of $CO_2$ and $(26/38)n_{O_2}$ moles of $H_2O$.

Consider a thermal-dynamically isolated system composed of 1 Litre of pure $O_2$ under STP (plus the required amount of $C_{25}H_{25}$ for complete combustion). Calculate the temperature change due to the combustion. The molar heat capacity of $CO_2$ and $H_2O$ are both approximately $30Jmol^{-1}K^{-1}$

From $Q=mc\Delta T$:
$$n_{wax}E_m^{wax}=n_{CO_2}c_{m,CO_2}\Delta T+n_{water}c_{m,water}\Delta T $$
$$ \left(\frac{1}{38}n_{O_2} \right)E_m^{wax}=\left(\frac{25}{38}n_{O_2} \right)c_{m,CO_2}\Delta T+\left (\frac{26}{38}n_{O_2} \right)c_{m,H_2O}\Delta T$$

$$\Delta T=\frac{(1/38)E_m^{wax}}{((25/38)c_{m,CO_2}+(26/38)c_{m,H_2O}}$$
$$\Delta T=\frac{E_m^{wax}}{25c_{m,CO_2}+26c_{m,H_2O}}=\frac{15MJmol^{-1}}{(25+26)\times 30Jmol^{-1}K^{-1}} \approx 10000 K$$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Those heat capacities seem a little low over the range of temperatures.  Also, that heat of combustion is probably for formation of liquid water; for water vapor, it would be about 1 MJ less.

Comment: @Chet Miller
 Thanks. So my working is not wrong then I guess? If the heat capacity is assumed to be constant. Never thought about he water vapour distinction though. Also $\Delta T $ is independent of the number of moles of $O_2$ initally present in the system?

Comment: Yes, it is independent of the number of moles of oxygen initially present.

Comment: Cross posted: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/159085/79678.

Comment: Specific heats are not constant over large temperature changes. Even more importantly, chemical equilibrium has to be calculated, formation of CO, OH, H etc.

Comment: It is relatively easy to generate spectacularly high temperatures given a small number of particles (molecules) in a perfectly thermally isolated chamber.